# Get Highest Percentage Values From An Entry Object Java

Tags: java

I am writing a program that tries to get the highest percentage of a category(where those categories are stored in an Entry object).What I am trying to do now is to store all the categories with the highest percentages,as it is a condition that can occur.So the question is:"How can I store those categories with the highest percentage values?"This is what my codes look like so far:

```
double biggestPercentage = 0;
String biggestPercentageCategory = null;
ArrayList<String> biggestPercentageCategories = new ArrayList<String>();
double percentage = 0;

System.out.println("\n");
System.out.println("Get user's most interested category:");
for(int i=0;i<entrySet.size();i++){
    allEntries = entrySet.get(i);
    if(allEntries.getValue() != 0){
        double calculatePercentage = allEntries.getValue();
        percentage = Double.parseDouble(df.format((calculatePercentage*100)/totalNumberOfContentForEachUser1));
        System.out.println("Percentage of " + allEntries.getKey() + ": " + percentage +"%");
        if(percentage > biggestPercentage){
            biggestPercentage = percentage;
            biggestPercentageCategory = allEntries.getKey();
        }        
    }
    if(percentage == biggestPercentage){
        biggestPercentageCategories.add(allEntries.getKey());    
    }
}

HashMap<String,String> hashmap = new HashMap();
if(percentage > biggestPercentage){
    hashmap.put(userName, biggestPercentageCategory);
}
else if(percentage == biggestPercentage){
    hashmap.put(userName, biggestPercentageCategories.toString());
}
for(Entry<String, String> str : hashmap.entrySet()){
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

The output looks like this:

Get user's most interested category:

```
Percentage of Entertainment_Culture: 12.5%
Percentage of War_Conflict: 12.5%
Percentage of Sports: 25.0%
Percentage of Hospitality_Recreation: 12.5%
Percentage of Human Interest: 12.5%<br>
Percentage of Education: 25.0%

dryice1993=[Entertainment_Culture, War_Conflict, Sports, Education]
```

where 'dryice1993' is just the person's username.

But the expected output I want is:

```
dryice1993=[Sports, Education]?
```

Comment: You might want to use sorting

Comment: can you do like this 1) sort the collection 2) find what is the percentage of first entry 3) find all entries with same biggest percentage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to add one line:

```
if(percentage > biggestPercentage){
        biggestPercentage = percentage;
        biggestPercentageCategory = allEntries.getKey();
        biggestPercentageCategories.clear();  // <-- add this one
}
```

Whenenver you find a new "highest percentage" then you just empty the bin with the old ones. These cannot contains entries with lower percentages.

Comment: make it `>=` and and put an if before clear to see if it is `!=` ?

Comment: @goldenparrot: no, because two lines below my snippet you see the real "add" operation. There the `==` is already in place which is just enough.

Comment: Oh A.H. method works!anyway I appreciate your effort in trying to help as well goldenparrot

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, in every iteration, you are taking a decision depending upon `biggestPercentage` so far.

So what you have to do is, shift these lines:

```
if(percentage == biggestPercentage){
    biggestPercentageCategories.add(allEntries.getKey());   
}
```

to another `for` loop below the one you have currently.

It's like this:

1. first iterate over all items
2. find the biggest percentage
3. then iterate again to see what are equal to biggest percentage
4. add them to the categories

EDIT:

insert

```
}
for(int i=0;i<entrySet.size();i++){
    percentage = allEntries.getValue();
```

before

```
if(percentage == biggestPercentage){
    biggestPercentageCategories.add(allEntries.getKey());   
}
```

in your code and try understanding it better.

Comment: For step 3,that is done outside the for loop right?And also what does it iterate through in that other for loop?